# How to avoid a loop here in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

In my R program I have a "for" loop of the following form:

```
for(i in 1:I)  
{  
res[i] <- a[i:I] %*% b[i:I]   
}
```

where `res`, `a` and `b` are vectors of length `I`.

Is there any straightforward way to avoid this loop and calculate res directly? If so, would that be more efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a matrix multiplication for 1d vectors?

Comment: Probably because I'm self-taught and clueless...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the "reverse  cumsum" of `a*b`

```
rev(cumsum(rev(a) * rev(b)))
```

Comment: time trials in process...  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft go ahead, but with `cumsum()` the multiplication only happens once, so it runs in _O(n)_. The loop should run in _O(n^2)_.

Comment: Even replacing `%*%` with `*` in Justin's, the median times are 360 and 87700 microseconds, so no suprise `cumsum` is faster by a lot.

Comment: Thanks for checking that @CarlWitthoft. I think the speedup is mostly due to the fact that the multiplication and addition only happens once.

Answer (score 2):

So long as `res` is already of length `I`, the for loop isn't "incorrect" and the apply solutions will not really be any faster.  However, using apply can be more succinct...(if potentially less readable)

Something like this:

```
res <- sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) a[i:I] %*% b[i:I])
```

should work as a one-liner.

---

Expanding on my first sentence.  While using the inherent vectorization available in R is very handy and often the fastest way to go, it isn't always critical to avoid for loops.  Underneath, the `apply` family determines the size of the output and pre-allocates it before "looping".

Comment: Just to be clear - this doesn't speed up the calculation over that of a loop, does it?

Comment: Correct.  If the code in the for loop was `res <- rbind(res, ...)` then the apply version would be much faster.

Comment: Also, using `sum(a[i:1] * b[i:1])` should be marginally faster than the matrix multiplication.